# How to move a document library with item level permissions from one site collection to other site collection?

Tags: document-library, permissions, export

I have a document library with item level permissions. how to export the complete document library with item level permissions from one site collection to another site collection?

Comment: is this one time only situation or will it occur occasionally? If 1st, did you consider sharegate 3rd party application? It is free for 30 days while lasts trial. client can be installed on any PC.

Comment: Be carefull using the 30 trial version from ShareGate, as it is a trial version and will exclude some files randomly. (Otherwise nobody would purchase a license)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to use export/import of the document library, like the following:

> Use Central Administration to export a site, list, or document library
>   in SharePoint Server
>
> You can use Central Administration to export a site, list, or document
>   library. You can only export one site, list, or document library at a
>   time.
>
> To export a site, list, or document library by using Central
>   Administration
>
> 1. Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is a
>      member of the Farm Administrators group.
> 2. Start Central Administration.
> 3. In Central Administration, on the home page, click Backup and
>      Restore.
> 4. On the Backup and Restore page, in the Granular Backup section,
>      click Export a site or list.
> 5. On the Site or List Export page, in the Site Collection section,
>      select the site collection from the Site Collection list, and then
>      select the site from the Site list.
> 6. If you are exporting a site, skip this step, Select the list or
>      document library from the List list.
> 7. In the File Location section, in the Filename box, type the UNC path
>      of the shared folder and the file to which you want to export the
>      list or document library. The file name must use the .cmp extension.
> 8. If the file already exists and you want to use this file, select the
>      Overwrite existing files check box. Otherwise, specify a different
>      file name.
> 9. If you want to export all the security and permissions settings with
>      the list or library, in the Export Full Security section, select the
>      Export full security check box.
> 10. If you want to specify which version of the list or library to
>       export, select one of the following versions from the Export
>       versions list:
>
>     - All Versions
>     - Last Major
>     - Current Version
>     - Last Major and Last Minor
> 11. When you have specified the settings that you want, click Start
>       Export.
> 12. You can view the status of all backup jobs at the top of the
>       Granular Backup Job Status page. You can view the status of the
>       current backup job in the Content Export section of the page. The
>       status page updates every 30 seconds automatically. You can manually
>       update the status details by clicking Refresh. Backup and recovery
>       are Timer service jobs. Therefore, it may take several seconds for
>       the backup to start.
>
> If you receive any errors, you can review them in the Failure Message
>   column of the Backup and Restore Job Status page. You can also find
>   more details in the .export.log file at the UNC path that
>   you specified in step 6.

Reference: [Use Central Administration to export a site, list, or document library in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/export-a-site-list-or-document-library#use-central-administration-to-export-a-site-list-or-document-library-in-sharepoint-server)

Comment: will this export the item level permissions as well? do it need to perform any additional steps to bring the item level permissions to destination location? Destination is within the farm and web application but a different site collection.

Comment: It should. But to be sure, make a PoC in your test environment